Interpreting Concordance Probability: Exclusion of Equal Outcomes and Role of Ties
The concordance probability $P(C)$ is defined as the likelihood that the model's predicted probabilities correctly rank the outcomes for two observations. It accounts for three types of pairwise comparisons:

Concordant pairs: When $\hat{p}(X_i) > \hat{p}(X_j)$ and $Y_i > Y_j$, or $\hat{p}(X_i) < \hat{p}(X_j)$ and $Y_i < Y_j$.
Discordant pairs: When $\hat{p}(X_i) > \hat{p}(X_j)$ and $Y_i < Y_j$, or $\hat{p}(X_i) < \hat{p}(X_j)$ and $Y_i > Y_j$.
Ties: When $\hat{p}(X_i) = \hat{p}(X_j)$.

The formula incorporates ties by adding half of their contribution:
$$
P(C) = \frac{\text{Number of concordant pairs} + 0.5 \times \text{Number of ties}}{\text{Total number of pairs where } Y_i \neq Y_j}.
$$
Let:

$C$ = number of concordant pairs,
$D$ = number of discordant pairs,
$T$ = number of tied pairs.

The total number of comparable pairs is $C + D + T$, and $P(C)$ becomes:
$$
P(C) = \frac{C + 0.5T}{C + D + T}.
$$

Question:
When calculating the concordance probability $P(C)$, we include ties by assigning them a weight of 0.5. However, we still exclude pairs where $Y_i = Y_j$.

How can $P(C)$ be interpreted as a "probability" when it is conditioned only on pairs with $Y_i \neq Y_j$?
Furthermore, is the inclusion of $0.5 \times \text{ties}$ a sufficient justification for calling it a probability, or is it merely a heuristic to handle ranking ambiguity?

